# How to create stream builder with back4app parse query data? flutter

Tags: listview, parse-platform, stream, back4app

yes this is a very basic question I manage to create a user app where you can place an order to be pickup say a laundry, now I creating a driver app to pick those laundry.

let say I have a class called 'LaundryPickUp', with column of PickUpDate (date), PredictedClothWeight (int), Owner(pointer to usernameclass), OwnerName(String, generated from user app).

I have two user who order at least 3
say

```
"PickUpDate" : 25-11-2021 16:00:30, "PredictedClothWeight" : 2,"Owner":{"__type":"Pointer","className":"_User","objectId":"MOpxjAJCl2"}}, "OwnerName" : "Ricky Des Safry", "ObjectId" : "MaPPWjckl"

"PickUpDate" : 27-11-2021 11:00:45, "PredictedClothWeight" : 3,"Owner":{"__type":"Pointer","className":"_User","objectId":"MOpxjAJCl2"}}, "OwnerName" : "Ricky Des Safry", "ObjectId" : "MaPPWjc32"

"PickUpDate" : 26-11-2021 18:41:30, "PredictedClothWeight" : 2,"Owner":{"__type":"Pointer","className":"_User","objectId":"MOpxj1321l2"}}, "OwnerName" : "David Tapp", "ObjectId" : "MaPPWj223"
```

Note : I do not make created at, updatedat on those run result

now I want to make STREAM query of this in the form of auto generated List of elevated button widget (where the driver can take that order). and elevated button widget would appear only OwnerName, and PickUpdate only.

can anyone help?

Comment: Would you mind to share the code of what you've tried so far? It might be easier for someone to help.

Comment: I dont know how to make stream :(

Comment: any suggestion where can I learn building stream of listview calling backend column of back4app?

Comment: Have you tried this guide? https://www.back4app.com/docs/flutter/parse-sdk/data-objects/flutter-query

Comment: hmm that page wasnt available when I go to docs last time :/ but I already check it, and I can query it.. not I just need to build as stream as I require the data to be immediatly upload to apps when new data arrive